# Kendo grid data-source filtering based on cascading dropdown list selected value

Tags: cascadingdropdown

I am working on Kendo UI,can anyone provide the solution how  to update Kendo grid datasource based on cascading drop-down list selected value.In Kendo demos I found cascading dropdownlists examples.

requirement:

**I have 3 dropdownlists,binding with 3 services,now I want to filter the grid data-source based on dropdownlist selected value.**

Comment: Below is my working fiddle,in this I can able to filter the dropdownlist's but not the grid.Based on 3rd dropdownlist orderid ,I need to filter the those records in the grid.

Please help me on this.
Thank You...


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/6qFCw/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Hai,

          In onchange event of thrid dropdownlist,you need to filter the grid datasource based on codition
              Change:filterGrid

           and a create function:
               function filterGrid() {
                dataSource.filter([
                { field: "orders", operator: "equals", value: $("#OrderID").val() }
                ]);
            }
```